# Which-key like in doom emacs: Symbol's value as variable is void: some-map

Tags: key-bindings, error

I would like to integrate which-key like doom emacs with "space" in my configuration, but I get the error: Symbol's value as variable is void: some-map

```
;; shows shortcuts, when clicking C-x                                                     |
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/dave/.emacs.d/elpa/which-key-20220811.1616/which-key.el") |
(require 'which-key)                                                                      |
(which-key-mode)                                                                          |
                                                                                          |
(define-key some-map "f" '("foo" . command-foo))                                          |
(define-key some-map "b" '("bar-prefix" . (keymap)))                                      |
(setq my-map (make-sparse-keymap))                                                        |
(define-key some-map "b" (cons "bar-prefix" my-map))                                      |
```

Comment: Did you cut-and-paste from a tutorial? You'll need to change `some-map` above (which was probably just a "fake" example) to the real map that you want to use.

Comment: @NickD: Post that as an answer? Or maybe OP wants to delete the question, if that's indeed the problem?

Comment: @NickD I did not know, what keymaps are.

Answer (score 1):

;; shows shortcuts, when clicking C-x

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/dave/.emacs.d/elpa/which-key-20220811.1616/which-key.el")
(require 'which-key)
(which-key-mode)
(setq some-map (make-sparse-keymap))
(define-key some-map "f" '("foo" . command-foo))
(define-key some-map "b" '("bar-prefix" . (keymap)))
(setq my-map (make-sparse-keymap))
(define-key some-map "b" (cons "bar-prefix" my-map))
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC") some-map)
```

see also here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymaps.html